# how to remove the first occurence of an integer in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my code:

```
positions = []
for i in lines[2]:
    if i not in positions:
        positions.append(i)
print (positions)
print (lines[1])
print (lines[2])
```

the output is:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['is', 'the', 'time', 'this', 'ends']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '5']
```

I would want my output of the variable "positions" to be; ['2','3','4','1','5']
so instead of removing the second duplicate from the variable "lines[2]" it should remove the first duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reverse your list, create the positions and then reverse it back as mentioned by @tobias_k in the comment:

```
lst = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '5']

positions = []
for i in reversed(lst):
    if i not in positions:
        positions.append(i)

list(reversed(positions))
# ['2', '3', '4', '1', '5']
```

Comment: Alternatively, could use `positions.insert(0, i)` or `positions[:0] = [i]` to insert at the front, but `append` and a second reverse is probably faster.

Comment: @tobias_k: appending and reversing is definitely going to be faster.

Comment: thank you so much, but i used a simpler method to reverse "positions" the second time; instead of "list(reversed(positions))" i used positions.reverse()

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to first detect what values are duplicated before you can build `positions`. Use an `itertools.Counter()` object to test if a value has been seen more than once:

```
from itertools import Counter

counts = Counter(lines[2])
positions = []
for i in lines[2]:
    counts[i] -= 1
    if counts[i] == 0:
        # only add if this is the 'last' value
        positions.append(i)
```

This'll work for any number of repetitions of values; only the last value to appear is ever used.

You could also reverse the list, and track what you have already seen with a set, which is faster than testing against the list:

```
positions = []
seen = set()
for i in reversed(lines[2]):
    if i not in seen:
        # only add if this is the first time we see the value
        positions.append(i)
        seen.add(i)
positions = positions[::-1]  # reverse the output list
```

Both approaches require two iterations; the first to create the `counts` mapping, the second to reverse the output list. Which is faster will depend on the size of `lines[2]` and the number of duplicates in it, and wether or not you are using Python 3 (where `Counter` performance was significantly improved).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dictionary to save the last position of the element and then build a new list with that information

```
>>> data=['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '5']
>>> temp={ e:i for i,e in enumerate(data) }
>>> sorted(temp, key=lambda x:temp[x])
['2', '3', '4', '1', '5']
>>>
```